# Add Reply-To Email to WFFM Send Email Message Save Action

Tags: wffm

I'm attempting to add a reply-to address to an email I'm sending via WFFM 8.1. The save action I am using is "Send Email Message." The email being sent includes the email address of the user filling out the associated form. I would like to use the user's email as the reply-to address.  In the email message editor, I do not see a reply-to email option so I assume I will need to write a custom save action. My question is twofold:

1. Is it possible to add a reply-to address to the "Send Email Message" save action with out-of-the-box WFFM?
2. If this functionality is not available out-of-the-box, it possible to extend the functionality of the "Send Email Message" save action to include a reply-to email while preserving the following UI that accompanies the save action?
   [image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is the function of a reply-to? For the reciever in the mail? You already have the "To:" field where you can click the down arrow to get an e-mail field (the one users fill out in the form). IF you have added an e-mail field to your form already.

Comment: Here's a post detailing what a reply-to field does: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2761914?start=0&tstart=0. Essentially, the client wants to be able to hit reply to send an email back to the individual who filled out the form rather than fishing through the email for the individual's email address and pasting it into the "To" field.

Comment: I would suggest to use **Email Experience Manager** for e-mail sending and there you have much more functionality like **Reply To**.

Comment: @TamásTárnok, how would you use EXM for save action?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to override for the `SendEmail` method in the `processMessage` pipeline (patched in  the `/App_config/Include/Sitecore.Forms.Config`)

With something like this:

```
using Sitecore.Form.Core.Pipelines.ProcessMessage;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace Arktouros
{
    public class PressMessageOverride
    {
        public void SendEmail(ProcessMessageArgs args)
        {
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(args.Host);
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = args.EnableSsl;
            if (args.Port != 0)
            {
                smtpClient.Port = args.Port;
            }
            smtpClient.Credentials = args.Credentials;
            smtpClient.Send(this.GetMail(args));
        }

        private MailMessage GetMail(ProcessMessageArgs args)
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(args.From, args.To.ToString(), args.Subject.ToString(), args.Mail.ToString())
            {
                IsBodyHtml = args.IsBodyHtml
            };
            //your reply to goes here, set to be the from address of the form being submitted
            mail.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress(args.From));

            if (args.CC.Length > 0)
            {
                mail.CC.Add(args.CC.ToString());
            }
            if (args.BCC.Length > 0)
            {
                mail.Bcc.Add(args.BCC.ToString());
            }
            args.Attachments.ForEach(delegate (Attachment attachment)
            {
                mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            });
            return mail;
        }
    }
}
```

then update the config file to point to your new class:

replace: 
`<processor type="Sitecore.Form.Core.Pipelines.ProcessMessage.ProcessMessage, Sitecore.Forms.Core" method="SendEmail" />`

with

```
<processor type="NamespaceOfYourClass, YourDLL" method="SendEmail" />
```

and away you go, for info this is not fully tested, but should work fine.